# Oracle query with references

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, aggregate

Can you do this in plain SQL?  I need to do something like this:

```
initial_value = 10000
start_value = 10000

LOOP
  start_value = start_value * (1 + (['table column'] / 100));
  percent = ((start_value - initial_value) / initial_value) * 100;
END
```

So, basically I am aggregating as the query runs.  But referring to previous values in the query, I do not think this is possible.   In the end, this needs to be a record set which I can open up a cursor and have the application read.

Hoping not to have to create an object type, or use temporary tables.  It seems kind of a simple operation, query and run some aggregates, but I think it is keeping the running numbers which is a problem.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be great.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Why do you think there will be a problem? Better just ask your question and don't speculate on what can and can't be done - you are very likely to be wrong. Depending on the exact requirement (which is still not clear), you may need analytic functions. These have existed in Oracle for many years, people use them all the time. Your focus should be on stating the problem as clearly as possible, and on providing meaningful test data and desired output in addition to a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

With a table defined and populated as

```
create table some_table (table_column  number);

insert into some_table (table_column) values (1000);
insert into some_table (table_column) values (2000);
insert into some_table (table_column) values (3000);
insert into some_table (table_column) values (4000);
insert into some_table (table_column) values (5000);
insert into some_table (table_column) values (6000);
insert into some_table (table_column) values (7000);
insert into some_table (table_column) values (8000);
insert into some_table (table_column) values (9000);
insert into some_table (table_column) values (10000);
```

We can use the `LAG` analytical function to get what you're after. There may be more compact ways to accomplish this but the following should serve as a demonstration:

```
WITH cteValues AS (SELECT 10000 AS START_VALUE,
                          10000 AS INITIAL_VALUE
                     FROM DUAL)
SELECT 1 + (TABLE_COLUMN / 100) +
         LAG(START_VALUE + 1 + (TABLE_COLUMN / 100), 1, INITIAL_VALUE)
           OVER (ORDER BY TABLE_COLUMN) AS RUNNING_VALUE,
       ((1 + (TABLE_COLUMN / 100) +
           LAG(START_VALUE + 1 + (TABLE_COLUMN / 100), 1, INITIAL_VALUE)
             OVER (ORDER BY TABLE_COLUMN)) - INITIAL_VALUE) / INITIAL_VALUE AS PERCENT_VALUE
  FROM cteValues c
  CROSS JOIN SOME_TABLE s;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a1ca/15)

Best of luck.

Comment: This query is interesting.   I'll have to work with it.   There are however, 2 other pieces of information I need from the query, which I forgot to mention.   The first is the date from the SOME_TABLE.  (Say date_received).   I also need an identifier which is in SOME_TABLE (Say ticker).    So, can this query also return these values also in the CROSS JOIN part?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a function that return PIPELINED rows. See below sample.

```
CREATE TYPE num_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

--here you can apply your program logic
CREATE FUNCTION get_nums(start_num NUMBER, end_num NUMBER) RETURN num_table PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
    FOR num_loop IN start_num..end_num
    LOOP
        PIPE ROW(num_loop);
    END LOOP;
END;
/

SELECT *
  FROM table(get_nums(100, 200));
```